# Decision Tree status column & related numerical value column

Tags: scikit-learn, numeric, decision-tree, categorical-data

I have a data including two columns where one is categorically shows the status of the feature & the other one numerically shows the related value. Just like below:

[image: Status & Value columns]

I want to run a decision tree algorithm via scikit learn on this data. I am not sure how to deal with these two columns because conceptually I cannot figure out how to bond these tho very correlated features. Basically, we are not supposed to leave null data, however, this one is supposed to be null in numerical column by nature. If we make it "0", it has another meaning.

So, how should I pre-process this data to have the decision tree algorithm work properly?

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far, and what *specific programming* issues you face; SO is not a code design service, I kindly suggest you re-read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My prefossor provides a reasonable answer as below.

First, fill the null cells with "0".
If you plug the data into decision tree algorithms with these two features, we have two cases:

- If "Status" comes first:
  The tree will split 0's and 1's into two branches. Under 0, all Amount values will be already 0, hence this feature will not be chosen. Under 1, there will not be any 0 Status.
- If "Amount" comes first: All Status 0's will go under only one branch and they will get together with the ones that are very small amounts.

So, If the Amount data is noisy, it might be helpful to keep the Status column. Otherwise, I would remove the Status column.